# URL rewrite more than one php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got an problem with url rewriteing.
First of all i am starting to think that i am making mistake in the structure of my webpage.
I made more than one php file. I think that this is mistake because in all tutorials and samples urls they are using in .htaccess only index.php.

Info
 1. I got in navigation tab index.php section1.php section2.php section3.php section4.php
 2. In index.php i only have an basic information that won't change much.
 3. In each section.php file i am echoing out list of articles.
 4. each aricle got id and i am using it to echo out information when user clicks on article link.
 5. link to article  "http://www.example.com/section1.php?id=607575"
 6. In each section.php file i got more than one page.
 7. For now my links to section page looks like this "http://www.example.com/section1.php?page=1".
Questions

Qestions

1. Should i better echo out all information on index.php page by getting information from url?
2. If now my link looks like this `<a href="http://www.example.com/section1.php?page=1>section1</a>` do i need to manually rewrite them OR it dose not matter, .htaccess will do the job?
3. if i need to rewrite url will it looks like this? `<a href="http://www.example.com/section1.php/section1/page/1">section1</a>`
4. How to rewrite urls so they look like this www.example.com/section1/page/1  and www.example.com/section1/article/607575 (i know it's bad to use only numbers, i just need to understand how it works,then i will figure it out,how to replace it with article name).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is how you would rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /path/to/section1.php?page=$ [QSA,L]
```

I'm not very used to mod_rewrite but that should work. You might have to rewrite rule for ?article too.

If this was not answered correctly, please refer to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks for response! It worked . But why it's not effected by css anymore?

Comment: You must make the CSS file global. So if your CSS file right now is href="style.css" you must make it "www.example.com/css/style.css".

Comment: Works like charm except one thing. Actually two things. Gives me an error, when i try to add multiple rewriteconds... I newd something like this `RewriteRule ^(.+)$/path/to/section1.php?page=$ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$/path/to/section1.php?article=$ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$/path/to/section2.php?page=$ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$/path/to/section2.php?article=$ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$/path/to/section3.php?page=$ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$/path/to/section3.php?article=$ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$/path/to/section4.php?page=$ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$/path/to/section4.php?article=$ [QSA,L]`

Comment: You can try using what Stephanie did or take away the [L] from all but the last one.

Comment: Both variations didn't worked. I think i need to call RewriteCond before I call RewriteRule again, but that isn't working as planed. And your example shows example.com/section1 but i need /example.com/section1/page/1 and after user choose article /example.com/section1/23453 Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From:   `http://www.example.com/section1/page/1`

To:     `http://www.example.com/section1.php?page=1`

`RewriteRule ^section(\d+)/page/(\d+)$ /path/to/section$1.php?page=$2`

From:   `http://www.example.com/section1/article/607575`

To:     `http://www.example.com/section1.php?id=607575`

`RewriteRule ^section(\d+)/article/(\d+)$ /path/to/section$1.php?id=$2`

Comment: hi Stephanie. Thanks for response. I am struggling for many hours now and can't do this. I read apache mod rewrite manual and still couldn't get it right. I assume your suggestion isn't working because of section$1 $1 part. I need for example: dom.com/cars.php?page=1 to dom.com/cars/page/1 and when user clicks on article dom.com/cars.php?id=3452 to dom.com/cars/id/3452 also i got an error when i tried to use multiple lines of code i nead to add dom.com/bikes.php?page=1 ect. to rewrite.